# Test failed in Numpy pre-installed with Mac OS X

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the python 2.7 and numpy 1.6 pre-installed in Mac OSX. The download page advised to test it with nose after installation to see if the installation went correctly, so I did

```
import numpy as np
np.test('full')
```

and it gives me the following errors:

```
Running unit tests for numpy NumPy version 1.6.1 NumPy is installed in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy Python version 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] nose version
1.3.0
```

(*here I omit the dots that occurred during the testing process*)

```
======================================================================
FAIL: Test basic arithmetic function errors
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 215, in knownfailer
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/tests/test_numeric.py", line 321, in test_floating_exceptions
    lambda a,b:a/b, ft_tiny, ft_max)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/tests/test_numeric.py", line 271, in assert_raises_fpe
    "Type %s did not raise fpe error '%s'." % (ftype, fpeerr))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 34, in assert_
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: Type <type 'numpy.complex64'> did not raise fpe error ''.

====================================================================== FAIL: test_kind.TestKind.test_all
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/f2py/tests/test_kind.py", line 30, in test_all
    'selectedrealkind(%s): expected %r but got %r' %  (i, selected_real_kind(i), selectedrealkind(i)))   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 34, in assert_
    raise AssertionError(msg) AssertionError: selectedrealkind(19): expected -1 but got 16

---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 3552 tests in 38.427s

FAILED (KNOWNFAIL=3, SKIP=1, failures=2) <nose.result.TextTestResult run=3552 errors=0 failures=2>
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction to get this problem fixed? That'd be much appreciated. Thanks!